# How to build a matrix that contains counts of matches between tables?

Tags: mysql

Other than diving in brute force one query at a time, I'm stumped on a repeatable efficient way of doing this:

- assume I have 4 ticketed events around the country (EventA-2018,
  EventB-2018, EventC-2018, and EventD-2018)
- I now need to present a simple 4x4 table with counts of people who attended X also attended Y
- each event has an associated MySQL table (e.g., event-a-2018-buyers, event-b-2018-buyers, etc.) and each one contains
  a single column called *email* representing the buyer.

The resulting table should look something like this:

```
  
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+  
|            | EventA-2018 | EventB-2018 | EventC-2018 | EventD-2018 |  
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+  
|EventA-2018 |     X       |     a       |     b       |     c       |  
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+  
|EventB-2018 |     a       |     X       |     d       |     e       |  
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+  
|EventC-2018 |     b       |     d       |     X       |     f       |  
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+  
|EventD-2018 |     c       |     e       |     f       |     X       |  
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

So the top row basically says, "Of the people who bought tickets for EventA-2018, there were a who also bought for EventB-2018, b who also bought for EventC-2018, and c also who bought for EventD-2018".

The diagonal isn't important since it would represent 100% each time.

Out of the 12 remaining cells, I obviously only need to fill in 6 since they are repeated (e.g., a,b,c,d,e,f).

There are actually more than 4 events and each one happens each year, but I'm assuming I can adapt any solutions to expand accordingly.

My current MySQL skills stop just after doing a join on two of the event tables.  So I could easily figure out the 6 inner joins I need to run to fill in this matrix and manually build the table, but I'm hoping there is a more programmatic way that will allow me to automate it into a dashboard.

Here is how I would fill in one cell at a time:

```
SELECT
    Count( eventa_2018.email ) as cell_a
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT email FROM eventa_2018
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT email FROM eventb_2018 ON eventa_2018.email = eventb_2018.email;
```

SIDE NOTE: A completely different approach I'm considering is to combine all tables into one with only two fields - email, event.  Then I could strip out everyone who only attended one event.  For the rest, I could create a simpler report showing the counts of people who attended each combination of more than one event (whereas the table above only shows two events at at time).  The resulting business case for all of this is to learn where to invest in more cross promotion of events and create segments of most valuable customers.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code. And if you have a table called eventa_2018 then this is highly symptomatic of appallingly poor design.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment.

A normalised schema might look something like this:

```
event year buyer
a     2018 joe@amgil.com   
b     2018 kat@plape.com
```

Start there. See my comments above, and then get back to us.